# "take me along with you" vs "take me along"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

As I see it in a dictionary, "take someone along" means "take someone along with you when you are going somewhere". Why do you add "with you" after "take me along" if this phrasal verb contains this meaning by itself?

> If you are going to the zoo, **take me along**.
>
> If you are going to the zoo, **take me along with you**.

Comment: To make it absolutely clear. Also, adding "with you" makes the sentence more personal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do you add "with you" after "take me along" if this phrasal verb contains this meaning by itself?

That is one of thousands of examples where you can say something concisely or verbosely. You can add more words, or remove words and make it shorter.  If you closely examine your own native language, it's probably the same.

One small example: In languages which inflect verbs, you don't always have to say the subject of the sentence because it's implied.

"I go", or just "[I] go".

And, why do you include optional words? To stress them, add emphasis, modify the meaning in a subtle way. Or, to be more loquacious.